# TensorFlow outer product of two 2-rank tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Suppose I have a rank two tensor, `[[a,b],[c,d]]`(in general a m-by-n matrix).

I want to expand every element by a 2-2 identity matrix(outer product) and result in

```
[[a, 0, b, 0],[0,a,0,b],[c,0,d,0],[0,c,0,d]].
```

What is the most efficient way to implement it in tensorflow?

This operation appears a lot in the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to do this in 2-step process.
If I have a m-by-n matrix, and a 2-2 identity matrix.
First I will enlarge (repeat) the matrix to "2m-2n matrix"
and then multiply by the enlarged identity matrix (2m-2n matrix). As following shows.

```
import tensorflow as tf
#Process 1  repeat the tensor in 2D.
#e.g. [1,2,3,4]  --> [[1,1,2,2],[1,1,2,2],[3,3,4,4],[3,3,4,4]]

# assuming  m x n idenity matrix e.g. [1,2,3],[4,5,6]] , m=2,n=3
id_matrix_size=2  # size of identity matrix (e.g. 2x2 3x3 ...)
m=2
n=3
mytensor=tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6] ],dtype = tf.float32)

# similar to np.repeat in x-dimension.
flatten_mytensor=tf.reshape(mytensor,[-1,1])  
a=tf.tile(flatten_mytensor,  [1, id_matrix_size])
b=tf.reshape( a, [m,-1])

# tile in y-dimension
c=tf.tile(b,[1,id_matrix_size])
d=tf.reshape(c,[id_matrix_size*m,id_matrix_size*n])

#Process 2  tile identity matrix in 2D. 
identity_matrix=tf.eye(id_matrix_size) # identity matrix 
identity_matrix_2D= tf.tile(identity_matrix,[m,n])

#Process 3  elementwise multiply
output = tf.multiply(d,identity_matrix_2D )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(output) )
#output :
#[[1. 0. 2. 0. 3. 0.]
# [0. 1. 0. 2. 0. 3.]
# [4. 0. 5. 0. 6. 0.]
# [0. 4. 0. 5. 0. 6.]]
```

And also, a def is more convenient if lots of implements are needed.

```
def Expand_tensor(mytensor,id_matrix_size):
    m=mytensor.shape[0]    
    n=mytensor.shape[1]
    # similar to np.repeat in x-dimension.
    flatten_mytensor=tf.reshape(mytensor,[-1,1])  
    a=tf.tile(flatten_mytensor,  [1, id_matrix_size])
    b=tf.reshape( a, [m,-1])

    # tile in y-dimension
    c=tf.tile(b,[1,id_matrix_size])
    d=tf.reshape(c,[id_matrix_size*m,id_matrix_size*n])


    # tile identity matrix in 2D. 
    identity_matrix=tf.eye(id_matrix_size) # identity matrix 
    identity_matrix_2D= tf.tile(identity_matrix,[m,n])

    #elementwise multiply
    output = tf.multiply(d,identity_matrix_2D )
    return output

mytensor=tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6] ],dtype = tf.float32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(Expand_tensor(mytensor,2)) )
```